# Why images aren't responsive in FF and IE?

Tags: image, responsive-design, responsiveness

I have big problem. Tried almost everything and it still doesn't work properly.

Everything works fine in Opera, but in FF and IE images aren't responsive. I mean they are displayed with original dimensions instead of fitting a div (like in Opera).

Here is the link: http://gksolutions.pl/oferta/strony-internetowe

Any help my friends? I literaly wasted 2 days on it already. It's not bootstrap, just a simple grid system.

How does it look in FF and IE:

[image]

How it looks in Opera

[image]

Basically images aren't scaling properly in FF and IE, although row div is set to 350px height and img is styled with:

```css
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
```

Comment: A link is considered poor on SO. Please provide a minimum, complete and verifiable example in the question itself. You'll increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Ok, ill provide full description

Comment: Looks good on my IE11 and FF

Comment: It's nothing to do with the images. It's the `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` on the parent elements. Remove those and everything works fine in Firefox and IE.

Comment: but then how can i center vertically the text div? use translate?

Comment: and why it works properly on start page: http://gksolutions.pl/ (in parallax sections)? its table, but image resizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't with the images, but with the `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` on the parent elements.

As far as I can tell, adding `table-layout: fixed;` after `display: table;` (in `.element .row .row_inner > div`) solves the layout problem.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout for more information on what `table-layout` does.

Comment: btw I use it to center vertically elements. Is that a bad habit?

Comment: @luka5z It's not a bad habit, but you'll need to ensure you understand how the table layout algorithm's work, so you can debug issues when they occur. In my experience, Firefox, IE, Safari and Chrome all do things very slightly differently! If you can afford to drop support for older browsers, I'd highly recommend using flexbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems in IE11, but if I'm understanding you right, just use images as div backgrounds (css `background-image`) and everything will be fine.